# How to leverage logstash to index data but not generating extra fields from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am testing ElasticSearch to handle around 1 billion small doc (only 8 fields). When i use logstash to index data, it adds other fields like "message", "@version", "@timestamp" that not useful to my case and seems to consume lots of doc size. Is there a way to only index the fields defined in configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply add the following [`mutate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) in your Logstash configuration:

```
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp", "message" ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add and remove fields to remove use following snippet in your conf file.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp", "message", "@version" ]
  }
}
```

To add new field use following snippet.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" }
  }
}
```